# Setting an Integer to something, but It won't change. Why?

Tags: c#, json.net

Currently I have this function that loads an integer from a JSON file, and then it sets the ExeBalance to the Integer it found in the JSON file however when checking the breakpoints I see that the JSON `JBalance` gets retrieved correctly, but it won't change the ExeBalance integer.

It is setting it to the JSON object, but It won't change the ExeBalance value:

```
ExeBalance = saveDataJson.JBalance;
```

This is my code:

```
namespace Money_Simulator
{
  public class DataObject
  {
    public int JBalance { get; set; }
  }
  
  internal class DataHandler
  {
    public int ExeBalance = 0;
    
    public void AddBalance(int amt)
    {
      ExeBalance = ExeBalance + 1;
      Console.WriteLine(ExeBalance);
    }
    
    public void LoadSave()
    {
      string filePath = Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "savedata.json"
      );
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

      string saveDataContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
      var saveDataJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataObject>(
        saveDataContent
      );

      ExeBalance = saveDataJson.JBalance;
      Console.WriteLine("ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json:");
      Console.WriteLine(ExeBalance);
    }
  }
}
```

The contents of savedata.json are `{"JBalance": 5}`.

Comment: What are the contents of `savedata.json`?

Comment: B.t.w. it's an integer not an intenger.

Comment: {"JBalance": 5}

Comment: Have you examined the value of `saveDataContent.JBalance`? My suspicion is that that field is not being set, either because it's missing in the incoming JSON stream, or a difference in the property name (or structure).

Comment: The `saveDataContent.JBalance` is correct, on further examination I see that in the `LoadSave()` function the `ExeBalance` prints out as the value of `JBalance`, but when the `ÀddBalance()` runs it makes the `ExeBalance` back to 1

Comment: "_but when the ÀddBalance() runs it makes the ExeBalance back to 1_" No, it doesn't set it back. You just invoke AddBalance on a **different** `DataHandler` instance, which is not the `DataHandler` instance that you used to calll LoadSave. (That's the only way how what you described could make any sense...)

Comment: Show us the JSON!

Comment: @PaulSinnema `{"JBalance": 5}`

Comment: Can't reproduce, `handler.ExeBalance` is `5` after running `LoadSave()`. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/idMLuD.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], and see [ask].

Comment: `using System;`
`using Newtonsoft.Json;`
`using System.IO;`

@dbc

Comment: By the way, you should dispose of your `StreamReader` via a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: @xJo - How do those 3 `using namespace` statements help to reproduce the problem?  My [linked fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/idMLuD) which includes the code in your question compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: Can you please also add the code which is using your class and showing the bahaviour you describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't understand how this should work. My guess is you would like to add an amount to the balance that is stored in your JSON. I've modified your code to do just that. The Load() returns the deserialized JSON object. The AddBalance then adds the amount (amt) and the Save then saves it to the JSON file. Here's the modified code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Money_Simulator
{
    public class DataObject
    {
        public int JBalance { get; set; }
    }

    internal class DataHandler
    {
        private const string FileName = @"..\..\..\savedata.json";

        public void AddBalance(int amt)
        {
            var data = Load();
            data.JBalance = data.JBalance + amt;
            Save(data);
        }

        private DataObject Load()
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, FileName);

            string saveDataContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            var saveDataJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataObject>(saveDataContent);

            Console.WriteLine($"ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: {saveDataJson.JBalance}");

            return saveDataJson;
        }

        private void Save(DataObject data)
        {
            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            File.WriteAllText(FileName, output);
        }
    }
}
```

In your main application do the following:

```
using Money_Simulator;

var handler = new DataHandler();

handler.AddBalance(1);
handler.AddBalance(1);
handler.AddBalance(1);
handler.AddBalance(1);
handler.AddBalance(1);
handler.AddBalance(1);
handler.AddBalance(1);
```

Result is:

```
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 10
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 11
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 12
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 13
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 14
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 15
ExeBalance was set to this value from reading savedata.json: 16
```

Comment: I see you made a variable called `handler` does it update every time someone clicks? if so the problem was that it was stuck on the first interaction in a loop (kinda)?

Comment: Did you try the code? This solution is not going to work if implemented in a multiuser environment. Just works for 1 instance no more.

Comment: Yeah, It worked, but I was just wondering if it was because It had already referenced it and couldn't update, but when you put it in a variable it needs to reference it every time meaning it could update.

Comment: You don't make much sense to me. What do you mean with 'but when you put it in a variable it needs to reference it every time meaning it could update'?

Comment: How would you describe it?

Comment: Huh, you're asking a question to a question? I've updated the answer. Is this what you mean?